# How to use "Image-Compressor" this plugin in my image uploading code?

Tags: npm, antd, image-compression

I have created this file using antd upload component. I want that when I upload the image, it should compress the size and quality max size is 2mb and send to backend. I have found the plugin, but I don't know how to use it. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

I have created the class component:

```
class Upload extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fileList: []
  };

  handleImageUpload = ({ onSuccess, onError, file }) => {

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.set("documentId", "");
    formData.append("image", file);
    console.log(base_url);
    axios .post(`${base_url}/uploadImage`, formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        onSuccess();
        this.props.form.setFieldValue(this.props.field.name, res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        onError();
      });
  };


  handleChange = ({ fileList }) => this.setState({ fileList });

  render() {
    const { fileList } = this.state;

    const uploadButton = (
      <div>
        <Icon type="plus" />
        <div className="ant-upload-text" style={{ color: "black" }}>
          Upload
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    const uploadedImage = (
      <img
        src={`${base_url}/viewImage`}
        alt=""
      />
    );
    return (
      <div className="clearfix">
        <MyUpload
          customRequest={this.handleImageUpload}
          listType="picture-card"
          fileList={fileList}
          // onPreview={this.handlePreview}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          {userDetails.imageId ? uploadedImage : uploadButton}
        </MyUpload>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to setup `webpack` in your project to use `image-compressor` module

Comment: https://github.com/powerbot15/image-compressor/issues/6

Comment: did u solve this issue ?  can u pls share code ? :)